# Create two alerts in jQuery from querying a string in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have the following string as a variable:

```
var name1 = '001-C6AL7_deepgreen_C3AE7_tankhakinavy_FJAG7_blackredmulti_FBAE7_tanbrown.jpg';
```

Which is provided by the server side configuration that I can't edit. With jQuery is there a way I can create an alert of all characters before and after a unique character (the hyphen '-').

So ideally, it'd alert first with `001` and then the second alert would be `C6AL7_deepgreen_C3AE7_tankhakinavy_FJAG7_blackredmulti_FBAE7_tanbrown.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split()` command of vanilla JavaScript ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) - no need for jQuery here:

```
var name1 = '001-C6AL7_deepgreen_C3AE7_tankhakinavy_FJAG7_blackredmulti_FBAE7_tanbrown.jpg';

var parts = name1.split( '-' );

alert( parts[0] );
alert( parts[1] );
```

Comment: Ah, great. That's a huge help - I'll look into the split() command more. Thank you!